# CSS hide all elements from a class except for the first one in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way to hide all elements of a particular class - except for the first one. I do realize that there are ways to do this in javascript, but this functionality would be for those **without javascript** enabled - hence why I'm looking for a **CSS only** solution, if there is any.

```
<div class="foo">Content 1</div> //not hidden
<div class="foo">Content 2</div> //hidden
<div class="foo">Content 3</div> //hidden
```

I can achieve this by using the `first-child` pseduo-class like:

```
.foo:first-child {
    display:block;
}
.foo {
    display:none;
}
```

But since IE6 doesn't support this pseduo-class, it won't work. Unfortunately, I can't cancel IE6 support (sigh), so I'm looking for a way to achieve this without using this particular selector.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be careful asking for a solution to a known deficiency (IE6 not supporting `:first-child` plus a myriad of other useful stuff) that might, essentially, add a huge amount of overhead (library, alternative setup, etc.), when a simple specialized class could accomplish the same effect. jQuery could [help in it's own way](http://www.thebrightlines.com/2010/01/31/hack-how-to-enable-first-child-in-ie6/), but that's a heavy cost if you don't need jQuery.

Comment: I totally agree with you, however, I'm trying to ensure the best possible UX for IE6 users with javascript disabled (yiekes, could it get worse?). Some might say that it'd be an impossible task.. :-D. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a class of the same style as fallback. since i am unsure if IE6 supports chaining (as far as i know, it doesn't), use a container to indicate.

```
/*hide all foo*/
.container .foo {
    display:none;
}

/*as suggested, might as well do this and drop the others altogether*/
.container .first-child { 
    display:block;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="foo first-child">Content 1</div> //not hidden
    <div class="foo">Content 2</div> //hidden
    <div class="foo">Content 3</div> //hidden
</div>
```

Comment: Would prefer a solution which didn't require additional classes, but I assume that since I'm dealing with IE6 that's just a dream. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: You need to split the rule into two as IE (and other non-buggy browsers like IE7 and WebKit) is supposed to ignore entire rules containing unrecognized selectors. But you may as well then discard the `:first-child` selector altogether and use the class.

Comment: I agree with @BoltClock, any solution is potentially bloated in reference to the simplest immediate fix.

Comment: Considering my options, this is by far the best solution. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

With the given markup, a CSS solution only for IE6 is impossible.  There is no way to target the first child, only general rule for all descendants.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I can think of...

```
<div class="foo">Content 1</div>
<!--[if IE 6]><div style="display:none"><![endif]-->
<div class="foo">Content 2</div>
<div class="foo">Content 3</div>
<!--[if IE 6]></div><![endif]-->​
```

OR

```
<div class="foo">Content 1</div>
<noscript><div style="display:none"></noscript>
<div class="foo">Content 2</div>
<div class="foo">Content 3</div>
<noscript></div></noscript>​
```

​

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FkCzB/

Comment: The least best solution. Yech, please only if there is absolutely no other way. `:)` Also, I don't think this actually resolves the real problem (I don't think the OP wants more markup either).

Comment: IE6 made us all forget our morals and ask for forgiveness of our sins, so sure, it "is" an approach, but no. Somebody needs to hit the "self-destruct" button on this old beast.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think somebody needs to hit the "self-destruct" button on IE altogether. IE10 is expected to release Wednesday March 14th **2012** and it may be the first IE up to par with Firefox 4 that was released Tuesday March 22nd **2011**

Comment: The market will dictate; for instance, I understand there's still quite a few users in China stuck on IE6 due to rampant Windows XP piracy. I don't bother with it, personally, but I feel I am probably lucky in that respect.

Comment: My relationship with IE6 is pretty basic... I don't care about anything except for basic functionality, even if the site looks terrible in IE6...

Comment: It's guaranteed to look terrible in IE6 if it's at all modern looking; it's just a matter if it's usable or not. It got my goat on several occasions (never more infamously than the [comma of death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/) that had my non-programming coworkers thinking I'd cracked), so I'm wistful only in the sense that it was a worthy competitor that proved your mettle... `:D`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8761/discussion-between-user1090389-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: Clicked on that link by accident... All I have to say OS I only wish I had the guts to put an upgrade your browser message on my site...